# Execute javascript only once a week

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, execute

I've got a question, im very new to javascript but i got this from the internet:

```
<script>
function lightbox_open(){
window.scrollTo(0,0);
document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';  
}
</script>
```

But i dont want to spam everyone this popup, so it only has to show 1 time every week on your pc, thought u can do this with a cookie. But im new to it so i cant get it working.

Someone that can help me out?

So if someone opens my page, show the popup. 2nd time he visits there is no popup, after 1 week the popup has to show again.

Comment: did you research about cookies?

Comment: Yes but im not good with Javascript so it all didnt work :(

Answer (score 2):

First create a function to set cookies:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

Then, a function to get a cookie:

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

and finally, check if cookie is set or else do the work and set the cookie

```
function checkCookie() {
    var lightbox = getCookie("lightbox");
    if (lightbox === "") { // Cookie not set
        lightbox_open();
        setCookie("lightbox", "seen", 7);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a cookie that gets deleted after a week:

```
document.cookie = 'preventSpam;max-age=604800';    // 7 * 24 * 60 * 60
```

Then check whether the cookie exists

```
if (document.cookie) {
    showSomePopup();
}
```

---

**Beware:** This is just a simplest possible demonstration. If you want to use cookies for more than this single use-case, you need to implement/import some kind of cookie getter/setter, as shown [in documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie).